# $\ln(x)$ Does Have a Laplace Transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

My introductory Laplace transform textbook says the following:

> The improper integral is defined in the obvious way by taking the limit:
>
> $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_a^R F(x) \ dx = \int_a^\infty F(x) \ dx$$
>
> provided $F(x)$ is continuous in the interval $a \le x \le R$ for every $R$, and the limit on the left exists. The parameter $x$ is defined to take the increasing values from $a$ to $\infty$. The lower limit $a$ is normally $0$ in the context of Laplace transforms. The condition $|F(x)| \le Me^{\alpha x}$ is termed "$F(x)$ is of exponential order" and is, speaking loosely, quite a weak condition. All polynomial functions and (of course) exponential functions of the type $e^{kx}$ ($k$ constant) are included as well as bounded functions. **Excluded functions are those that have singularities such as $\ln(x)$** or $1/(x - 1)$ and functions that have a growth rate more rapid than exponential, for example $e^{x^2}$.

(Bolding added by me for emphasis.)

My understanding is that the bolded part is false -- that is, $\ln(x)$ does have a Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L}\{ \ln(t) \} = - \dfrac{1}{s} [ \ln(s) + \gamma],$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Did the author make an error here?

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: I wouldn't even call that an error. With ln(x), the integral becomes _doubly improper_ and needs some justification of its existence.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Hmm, am I misinterpreting what the author is saying here? Is the author not claiming that, despite the fact that $\ln(t)$ is of exponential order, it’s Laplace transform does not exist? But it does exist.

Comment: No, I think you are interpreting it right, and also you are right in that the said transform exist. It is just that improper integrals are not defined unless we _define_ them (supposedly, in the obvious way). See, the authors took their time to deal with the issue at $\infty$ which all Laplace transforms have. They, however, didn't say a word about the issue at $0$ with $\ln$. Once the latter is also dealt with, everything you said becomes true. Short of that, the integral isn't defined.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ok, thanks for the clarification.